# Pandas: I want to sum a count if a string exists in any one of several columns and add this count to another dataframe with the searched term

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of videos with several columns of tags (strings) as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
videos = [(1, 'cool video','drama','horror'), (2, 'great video','sports','drama'), (3,'super video','comedy','horror')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=videos, columns=['video_id', 'title','tag_1','tag_2'])

    video_id    title       tag_1   tag_2
0   1           cool video  drama   horror
1   2           great video sports  drama
2   3           super video comedy  horror
```

Then I have another dataframe of search terms "df_search_terms" (which I could put into a list, for example). I want to see if these search terms occur at least once in one of the columns, and if so increment a counter in the dataframe of search terms (that is to say, OK we found this term once for the video, so += 1). To clarify, I want to know how many times the search term is matched in the dataframe containing +/- 1000 videos, for at least one of the tags.

Obviously I can make a count of matches, but I only want to increment the counter in df_search_terms once for that particular term. Something like this (which doesn't work, but I hope you get the gist):

```
search_count=df['tag_1'].str.contains('drama').sum()
df_search_terms.loc[(df_search_terms['search_term'] == 'drama'),'matching_videos'] +=1
```

The df_search_terms would be something like this:

```
search_terms = [('drama',0), ('horror',0), ('sports',0)]

df_search_terms = pd.DataFrame(data=search_terms, columns=['search_term', 'number_matching_videos'])

search_term     number_matching_videos
drama                            0
horror                           0
sports                           0
```

I imagine the solution lies in some clever use of apply but I'm afraid I can't figure it out.

I've tried using an "if" statement such as below, but I have an error:

```
if df.loc[(df['name'] == 'drama') | (df['tag_1'] == 'drama') | (df['tag_2'] == 'drama')]:
  df_search_terms.loc[(df_search_terms['search_term'] == 'drama'),'matching_videos'] +=1
```

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Your example output df is confusing. How would the counters look based on the input data you gave? Why are all of the item counts 0?

Comment: @G.Anderson yes, this was me creating the dataframe.

Indeed Vishnudev 'drama' would be 2 in this example, 'horror' would be 2, and 'video' would be 3 (if it existed in my df_search_terms).

Comment: Check my answer @BenTapscott

Comment: @Vishnudev would you mind checking out my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300467/pandas-sum-a-count-if-a-string-exists-at-least-once-in-any-one-of-several-colum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df_search_terms['number_matching_videos'] = 
 df_search_terms['search_term'].map(df.set_index('video_id')
                                    .stack()
                                    .str.get_dummies()
                                    .sum()))
```

Here is another way:

```
df_search_terms['number_matching_videos'] = (df_search_terms['search_term']
                                             .map((df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('tag')]
                                                   .stack()
                                                   .str.extractall('({})'.format(df_search_terms['search_term'].str.cat(sep='|')))[0]
                                                   .str.get_dummies()
                                                   .sum())))
```

Comment: What if the tag is something like `korean-drama`?

Comment: you could add a `sep` parameter to `.str.get_dummies(sep = '-')`

Comment: The point being the keyword could be inside the text.

Comment: Added another solution to deal with this potential issue

Comment: Cool. Thanks for considering that. @rhug123

Comment: As I explained below, my "real" df for videos contains other information (run time, for instance) and the columns I wish to match have very diverse names. I had to make a mockup for reasons of confidentiality. My apologies, I imagine this would change your answer.

Comment: @rhug123 thank you. Both of your answers sort of work on my test data. My issue is that on the example data, if I have "video" written in two columns then it is counted twice, whereas I want to add just +1 for one matched row only. 

I'm trying to post the code to show you but I'm having issues with the comments interface when using markdown for code.

Comment: @rhug123 I ended up using your solution above "Here is another way" because the other solutions were giving me NaN values on my real data, so thank you. The solution doesn't give +1 occurrence for each video, but +1 occurrence each time the search term finds a match in the tags, but I've accepted that as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to search and count all matches

```
search_re = '(' + df_search_terms.search_term.str.cat(sep=')|(') + ')'
```

Combine all tag columns into a single string and search

```
df_search_terms['number_matching_videos'] = (
    df.filter(regex='tag_*')
    .agg(' '.join, axis=1)
    .str.extractall(search_re)
    .notnull().sum()
)
```

Output

```
  search_term  number_matching_videos
0       drama                       2
1      horror                       2
2      sports                       1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My "real" df with videos actually has very diverse names such as "muscle" and "joint" (not just "tag"), as well as other columns that are not important for the search. I suppose we should change the regex somehow?

Comment: Just mention the columns `df[['col1', 'col2']]` instead of `df.filter(regex='tag_*')` @BenTapscott

Comment: Thanks again. It's returning NaNs for the moment, but I suspect I need to play with the composition of the search_re variable. 

The search_re was like this (with the code you supplied)

'(drama)|(horror)|(sport)|(comedy)' 

I changed the separator to the following:

search_re = '(' + df_search_terms.search_term.str.cat(sep='|') + ')'

which gives the following, also resulting in NaNs : 

'(drama|horror|sport|comedy)'

Comment: each word within a pair of brackets represents a group. You should not change the separator. @BenTapscott. It should look like `(drama)|(horror)|(sport)|(comedy)`

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works on my test data. I still have NaNs on my real data (a separate problem). My issue is that on this example df: 

        video_id  title                   tag_1  tag_2
0  1         cool video  drama  horror
1  2         great video  sports  drama
2  3         super video  video  scary horror

your code gives the following output. 

        search_term  number_matching_videos
0  drama           2
1  horror           2
2  sports           1
3  video           4

Video = 4, whereas I want video = 3 as it is just one matched row. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: @Visnudev sorry but I'm having issues with the comments interface when using markdown for code, hence the terrible formatting above. Basically my issue is that on the example data, if I have "video" written in two columns then it is counted twice, whereas I want to add just +1 for one matched row only.

Comment: I would advise you to ask another question about the new requirement. For the given post the answers work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have done as you suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68300467/pandas-sum-a-count-if-a-string-exists-at-least-once-in-any-one-of-several-colum